# Как сообщением в телеграмм-бота добавлять в переменную данные?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Есть например переменная:

```
bag = ['пистолет','АК-47','ТТ']
```

Как по кнопке (кнопку я сделаю) сделать так, что бы я написал в телеграмм бот и слово автоматом добавилось в переменную bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

@dp.message_handler()
async def test(message: types.Message):
    list.append(message.text)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'{list}')
```

на выходе имеем следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]